# Backbone events not firing after on demand loading element

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, user-interface, view

I'm using backbone and lazy loading views in a single page application as I need them. However, it appears doing this seems to be confusing the way backbone knows what my 'el' is when setting up events. Using the view definition below, I'm trying to get the code that fires on the submit button click or the input fields changing but right now, neither appear to work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

editaddressView = Backbone.View.extend({

    elementReady: false,

    initialize: function () {
        this.model = window.AccountData;

        this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);

        if ($('#section-editaddress').length == 0) {
            // Load UI
            $('#ajax-sections').prepend('<div class="section" id="section-editaddress" style="display: none;"></div>');
        }
        this.el = $('#section-editaddress');
    },

    events: {
        "click #edit-address-submit": "beginSaving",
        "change input": "updateModel",
        "change select": "updateModel"
    },

    render: function () {
        $(this.el).find("[name=address]").val(this.model.get('owner_address1'));

        // ...

        return this;
    },

    switchTo: function () {
        // Set menu state
        $('.js-NavItem').removeClass('active');
        $('#sN-li-personal').addClass('active');

        if (this.options.isPreLoaded)
            this.elementReady = true;

        if (this.elementReady) {
            this.renderSwitch();
        }
        else {
            var model = this;
            $('#section-editaddress').load('/ajax/ui/editaddress', function (response, status, xhr) {
                if (status == "error") {
                    $('#page-progress-container').fadeOut('fast', function () {
                        $('#page-load-error').fadeIn('fast');
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#section-editaddress').find('.routedLink').click(function (e) {
                        window.Router.navigate($(this).attr('href'), true);
                        return false;
                    });
                    model.delegateEvents();
                    model.elementReady = true;
                    model.render(); // First render
                    model.renderSwitch();
                }
            });
        }
    },

    renderSwitch: function () {
        // Abort showing loading progress if possible
        if (window.firstRunComplete) {
            clearTimeout(window.pageHide);
            // Change screen - Fade progress if needed
            $('#page-progress-container').fadeOut('fast', function () {
                $('#page-load-error').fadeOut('fast');
                var sections = $(".section");
                var numSections = sections.length;
                var i = 0;
                sections.hide('drop', { easing: 'easeInCubic', direction: 'left' }, 350, function () {
                    i++;
                    if (i == numSections) {
                        $('#section-editaddress').show('drop', { easing: 'easeInExpo', direction: 'right' }, 350).removeClass('hidden');
                        $.scrollTo($('#contentRegion'), 250, { margin: true });
                    }
                });
            });
        }

        // Switch complete
        window.changingPage = false;
    },

    updateModel: function () {
        var changedItems = {};
        if (this.model.get('csrf') != $(this.el).find("[name=csrf]").val())
            changedItems.csrf = $(this.el).find("[name=csrf]").val();
        // ...
    },

    beginSaving: function () {
        alert('test');
    }

});
});
```

Can anyone see what I've missed?

Comment: Instead of setting `el` directly, you should use [setElement](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement). I don't know that's the issue specifically, but it rewires events to a new DOM element.

Comment: @WiredPrairie Thanks so much! That fixed the problem. If you repost your comment as an answer I can give you the votes and the accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you need to change or modify the DOM element of a BackboneJS view manually, you should use [setElement](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement) rather than setting the property directly. It moves all of the event handlers to the newly attached DOM element and also sets the `$el` property. In addition, the function also detaches any existing event handlers.

So, in the code you pasted, you'd just change it to:

```
this.setElement($('#section-editaddress'));
```